# split string by top-most level parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following: `'(1) (2 (3))'`
I want to regex it to get the following array: `['1', '2 (3)']`
another example: `'(asd (dfg))(asd (bdfg asdf))(asd)'` -> `['asd (dfg)', 'asd (bdfg asdf)', ('asd')]`

I've tried to search how to do such  a regex, but I've only found ones that split by all the `()`, couldn't find anything to only filter the highest level of them.

Comment: This could be done with recursion `(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\))`. However that isn't supported in JavaScript.

Comment: Parentheses are not a regular language (it is a Type-2 grammar, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), so I believe universal regex is impossible to create

Comment: So if I do want to parse this, I'll have to start token-parsing and stuff? This is just what I wanted to avoid. too bad.

Comment: Instead of trying to parse this, try to get another input source. A input source like the one you've showed shouldn't be provided by any reasonable API - so if it is you that controls the output, change it

Comment: You can do that easily with [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive).

Comment: @baao, the thing i'm trying to parse is something pretty internal, which is, at most cases, parsed by a string compiler that is created by [Lex and Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/). I just wanted to see if I create a simple javascript converter from that format to JSON.

Comment: If there is not deeper nesting, you don't need recursion, try [`/\(((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*)\)/g`](https://jsfiddle.net/f0daveb2/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to resolve it with regex, here's a programmatic approach (although there are probably a lot more elegant ways to approach this issue ... particularly as it is very fragile, it relies on the parentheses to always be applied in the correct order).

```js
var string = "(asd (dfg))(asd (bdfg asdf))(asd)".split(''),
    result = [],
    fragment = '',
    countOpen = 0,
    countClosed = 0;
    
    
string.forEach(function (character) {
    fragment += character;
    
    if (character === '(') {
        countOpen += 1;
    }
    
    if (character === ')') {
        countClosed += 1;
    
        if (countOpen === countClosed) {
            result.push(fragment.slice(1, -1));
            fragment = '';
        }
    }
});

console.log(result);
```