# Splitting a string with nested parentheses at only the top level where "level" is determined by the parentheses

Tags: r, regex, string, recursion, pcre

I am trying to create a regular expression that will allow me to split the strings below on the central comma only.

```
str_1 <- "N(0, 1)"
str_2 <- "N(N(0.1, 1), 1)"
str_3 <- "N(U(0, 1), 1)"
str_4 <- "N(0, T(0, 1))"
str_5 <- "N(N(0, 1), N(0, 1))"
```

Think of them as parameters of the distributions. Now, I would like to split on the comma of the "top-level".

Some details: The numbers can be decimal numbers and both positive and negative. They will always be grouped either inside `U()`, `N()`, `LN()` or `T()` and separated by a comma. More groupings will be added later, so a more general solution is required or that it is easily extendable. What I am looking to do is split the expressions at the "top level" comma.

Now, the first case of `str_1` is straight forward using:

```
unlist(strsplit(str_1, ",", perl = TRUE))
```

Before I proceed, I need to know whether I have a nesting. I know that I will have more than one of either N, U, LN or T if there is a nesting. So to check, I did (for `str_2`):

```
length(attr(gregexpr("(N|LN|U|T)", str_2, perl = TRUE)[[1]], "match.length")) > 1
```

Having established whether I have a nesting (might be a cleaner way to test this?), I can proceed to work out the split for the remaining strings. However, this is where I am stuck. Given that I can't count the commas since the cases `str_2`, `str_3` and `str_4` would be ambiguous. How would I ensure that I only split on the central comma?

I expect the following outputs (so trimming away the first letter and parenthesis and last parenthesis)

```
# str_2
"N(0.1, 1)" "1"

# str_3
"U(0, 1)" "1"

# str_4
"0" "T(0, 1)"

# str_5
"N(0, 1)" "N(0, 1)"
```

I would like to stay with base R to reduce the number of dependencies for the code if possible. Any help is much appreciated.  It is also possible that this is not solvable by a regex, but requires a programatic approach possibly by recursion as suggeste in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310832/split-string-by-top-most-level-parentheses) Java question.

Comment: This problem is a dead ringer for a formal parser, not regex.  That being said, there might be a regex solution.

Comment: `strsplit(substring(str_2, 3, nchar(str_2)-1), ",(?![^()]*\\))", perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Best to use a lexical analysis tool (lex) and a grammar parser (yacc). There are however regex flavors that can scan nested structures.

It is also possible to do multiple parses with any regex engine:
1. annotate the nesting level to each parenthesis,
2. scan for opening and closing parenthesis of same level,
3. remove the nesting annotation.

See details at https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your character vectors are in the format you showed, you can achieve what you need with a single PCRE regex:

```r
(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|^N\()\K(?:\d+|\w+(\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*\)))(?=\s*,|\)$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zq2tdt/2). **Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s*,\s*|^N\()` - end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) and then a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars (`\s*,\s*`) or a `N(` string at the start of the string (`^N\(`)
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the current match memory buffer
- `(?:` - start of non-capturing group

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars
  - `(\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*\))` - Group 1 (needed for recursion to work correctly): a `(`, then any zero or more chars other than a `(` and `)`, then zero or more occurrences of the Group 1 pattern (recursed) and then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `(?=\s*,|\)$)` - immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and then a comma or `)` char at the end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/cM2zMx):

```r
strs <- c("N(0, 1)", "N(N(0.1, 1), 1)", "N(U(0, 1), 1)", "N(0, T(0, 1))", "N(N(0, 1), N(0, 1))")
p <- "(?:\\G(?!^)\\s*,\\s*|^N\\()\\K(?:\\d+|\\w+(\\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*\\)))(?=\\s*,|\\)$)"
regmatches(strs, gregexpr(p, strs, perl=TRUE))
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "0" "1"
#    
#    [[2]]
#    [1] "N(0.1, 1)" "1"        
#    
#    [[3]]
#    [1] "U(0, 1)" "1"      
#    
#    [[4]]
#    [1] "0"       "T(0, 1)"
#    
#    [[5]]
#    [1] "N(0, 1)" "N(0, 1)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation of the components of the expression as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Define `s` as a character vector of strings.  We compute the cumulative number of left parentheses minus the cumulative number of right parentheses and replace any comma for which that difference is 0 with semicolon and then split that.

To do that we use `gsubfn` which is like `gsub` except the replacement need not be a string but can be a proto object.  The `pre` method of the proto object runs at the beginning of each string and the `fun` method runs for each match of the pattern passed to `gsubfn`.  The `pre` method defined below sets `lev` to 0 where `lev` will hold the cumulative difference discussed above. `fun` is run at each match to left parenthesis, right parenthesis or comma and each time we get a match to:

- left parenthesis it will increment `lev`
- right parenthesis it will decrement `lev`
- comma it will emit semicolon replacing the comma if lev == 0

Remove the junk at beginning and end of the input `s` using `sub`, run `gsubfn` and then split the result at semicolon.  At the end we simplify the result into a data frame.   The output character vectors each have length 2 here but if they can have different lengths then omit `as.data.frame`.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(magrittr)


# s is char vec; rm is TRUE if 1st two chars & last one to be removed
# output is list of char vecs
Split <- function(s, rm = TRUE) {
  p <- proto(
    pre = function(this) this$lev <- 0,
    fun = function(this, x) {
      this$lev <- this$lev + ( x == "(" ) - ( x == ")" )
      if (x == "," && this$lev == 0) ";" else x
    }
  )

  if (rm) s <- sub("^..(.*).$", r"{\1}", s)
  s %>% gsubfn(r"{[\(\),]}", p, .) %>% strsplit(" *; *")
}

# test 1
s <- c(str_1 = "N(0, 1)", str_2 = "N(N(0.1, 1), 1)", str_3 = "N(U(0, 1), 1)", 
       str_4 = "N(0, T(0, 1))", str_5 = "N(N(0, 1), N(0, 1))")
s %>% Split %>% as.data.frame
##   str_1     str_2   str_3   str_4   str_5
## 1     0 N(0.1, 1) U(0, 1)       0 N(0, 1)
## 2     1         1       1 T(0, 1) N(0, 1)
```

Note that this can work with any number of arguments:

```
# test 2
w <- "lognormal(N(0, 1), 1), lognormal(0, U(0, 1)), beta(U(1, 1), 2), N(0, 1)"
w %>% Split(rm = FALSE)  %>% unlist
## [1] "lognormal(N(0, 1), 1)" "lognormal(0, U(0, 1))" "beta(U(1, 1), 2)"     
## [4] "N(0, 1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

If we consider that the structure remains the same, then we could do:

```
lapply(parse(text=strings), function(x)c(deparse(x[[2]]), deparse(x[[3]])))

[[1]]
[1] "0" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "N(0.1, 1)" "1"        

[[3]]
[1] "U(0, 1)" "1"      

[[4]]
[1] "0"       "T(0, 1)"

[[5]]
[1] "N(0, 1)" "N(0, 1)"
```

---

```
strings <- c("N(0, 1)", "N(N(0.1, 1), 1)", "N(U(0, 1), 1)", "N(0, T(0, 1))", "N(N(0, 1), N(0, 1))")
```